# При нажатии Space не срабатывает нажатия

Tags: c++, sdl

Мне нужно при нажатии на Space чтобы  делалася  некоторая операция. А именно переходило на  другой State. Я продебажился и у меня не срабатівает нажатия.

```
const Uint8* keyboardState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(nullptr);

if (keyboardState[SDL_SCANCODE_SPACE] == 1) 
{
    ..........
}
```

И не понятно почему. Нужна помощь